# Beginner Boolean compiling error

Tags: java, matrix, compilation, compiler-errors

I am very new to Java (doing a beginners university module) so sorry for the probably silly question. I am trying to verify whether a ragged `array` is a 'tridiagonal matrix'.

It is valid if it is of `length` 3 at the first level and of `length` `n − 1`, `n`, and `n − 1` at the second level. I intended to come up with a code to firstly verify the length is 3, then find the longest `length` `array` within it for `n`, then finally verify each `length`.

For whatever reason my code won't compile but I'm not seeing an error message, just a *red exclamation mark* on the class. I assume this means there are multiple errors. If anyone could point them out it would be a massive help.

```
static boolean isValidTridiagonal ( double [][] m)
{ 
    if (double [][]=new double [3][])
    { 
        int n = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
        {
            if(m[i].length > n)
            {
                n = m[i].length;

                if( (m[0].length = n-1) && (m[1].length = n) &&(m[2].length=n-1))
                {
                    return true

                }
                else
                {
                    return false
                }
            }
                else 
            {
                return false
            }
        }
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: You should use IDE like netbeans or eclipse and you can read the errors that tell you `Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need all that loops? If all arrays cannot be null, than

`static boolean isValidTridiagonal(double[][] m) {
        return m.length == 3 && m[0].length == m[1].length - 1 && m[2].length == m[0].length;
    }`

Comment: Thank you! I think I was overcomplicating the problem... Really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Foolish in the comments that it's helpful to use an IDE that can highlight syntax errors and other problems with the code, it really makes a huge difference. Apart from that, another general strategy is to always code in "baby steps": do only the minimal thing to test if the code works, compile and test often. And if you still have troubles, you can always comment out chunks of your code when searching for the offending bits.

Having said that, the errors that I see in your code are:

```
if (double [][]=new double[3][])
```

If you want to test the length of the input, you can do if (m.length == 3)

In

```
if( (m[0].length = n-1) && (m[1].length = n) &&(m[2].length=n-1))
```

you're not testing for equality, but rather trying to put the values n-1 etc into m[0].length, which is not going to work. What you probably meant was

```
if( (m[0].length == n-1) && (m[1].length == n) &&(m[2].length==n-1))
```

In

```
return true
```

you're missing a semicolon. The compiler is whiny about things like that and unless you use an IDE or learn to interpret the compiler error messages, it can be really painful to find such errors.

Finally, of course, the answer by vasste provides a much simpler solution to your actual task, so it's worth looking into that :).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a few braces at the end but, judging from your indentation, you just forgot to copy them.

You're missing semicolons from the end of the return lines.

The condition within this if statement `if (double [][] = new double [3][])` is not a valid expression. You simply want to evaluate the length, which you can do like `if (m.length == 3)`. You did the same thing later on.

The line including `(m[0].length = n-1) && (m[1].length = n) && (m[2].length=n-1)` is not valid because you are performing assignment (`=`) in all three cases. An equality check is the double equals operator `==`.

You do not return a value in every case. You can fix this by adding `return false;` after the closing brace of your first if statement, i.e. the last line of the function.

This is enough to get your code to compile. As mentioned in another answer though, your logic is confusing and without actually tracing it through I would speculate that it will not work as you would expect.

If I have understood your requirements correctly, you can rewrite the entire function as:

```
static boolean isValidTridiagonal ( double [][] m)
{
    return m.length == 3 &&
           m[0].length + 1 == m[1].length &&
           m[2].length + 1 == m[1].length;
}
```

A proper IDE - Netbeans, Eclipse, etc. - will give you fairly descriptive error messages to show you where you've gone wrong.

---

This is basically completely stylistic but I wish someone had pointed this out to me earlier. If you ever find yourself writing code in this form:

```
if( (m[0].length == n-1) && (m[1].length == n) && (m[2].length == n-1))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

know that you can save yourself so many lines without losing any readability by instead writing:

```
return (m[0].length == n-1) && (m[1].length == n) && (m[2].length == n-1);
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Really appreciate the explanation